Android fragment crashed when opened following immediate back button pressed
I have an android activity calling its fragment. It works fine in normal case. But if I abuse the activity by clicking another activity to start this one following by an immediate task bar back button pressed, the new activity will crash due to accessing to some data that is not fully loaded yet.
That is  (start activity) -> (immediate pressing back button)
will create the app.
How to solve this issue ?

Maybe post some code and the error you are getting

do u mind sharing the code ?

the code and the stack trace are important for anyone to give you a solution.
